# Why does meanStdDev() return [nan]?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, standard-deviation, laplacian

I want to calculate the standard deviation of an image using OpenCV in C++. However, I get very weird results.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    VideoCapture cap("Sample-Video.mp4");
    Mat frame;
    ret = cap.read(frame);

    Scalar m, stdv;
    cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Laplacian(frame, frame, CV_64F, 3);
    meanStdDev(frame, m, stdv);

    cout << stdv << endl;
}
```

It outputs always:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[-nan, 0, 0, 0]
[-nan, 0, 0, 0]
[-nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
[nan, 0, 0, 0]
```

and so on. Where's the problem?

Comment: In the code you show, `frame` is uninitialized.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the code where it gets initialized. Frame is a normal image taken from the cap. The code still does not work, so what could be wrong?

Comment: Make a [mcve] and perhaps we can check it out.

Comment: Done, now the code should work

Comment: It doesn't. It's best to try to compile it at home before updating it here :)

Comment: There's no loop in there, so how can it print more than one line?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is `OpenCV` known to leak a lot? I apparently have OpenCV 3.4.8 installed on my machine and `valgrind` throws out _a lot_ of memory leaks even for an automatic variable that just opens an `mp4` and then goes out of scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not that I've seen, but I don't have anything using `VideoCapture` in production. Could also be coming from whatever videoio backend it's using in your case.

Comment: @DanMašek Ok, great. I've downloaded the source and am compiling _latest and greatest_ now just to check if it's the old version that comes with Fedora 31 that causes the leaks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Have a look at this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5715

Comment: @eldesgraciado That looks just like the problem I had. I didn't manage to test the latest version though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It seems that the problem persists even in the latest version. It's been acknowledged by the devs but hasn't been resolved, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, by now, I figured out what the problem was myself. You are not allowed to use the same variable twice in the cvtColor() and Laplacian() functions, that means your source and destination can't be the same. Other programming languages like Python are able to deal with that problem, C++ however can not.

Anyway, here is my correct code how to get the Laplacian variance of an image:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

double give_laplacian(Mat *fr) {
    Scalar m, stdv;
    Mat gray, lap;

    cvtColor(*fr, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Laplacian(gray, lap, CV_64F);
    meanStdDev(lap, m, stdv, Mat());

    return pow(stdv.val[0], 2);
}

int main() {
    Mat frame;

    //here you get your frame, e.g. from a video with a cap etc.

    val = give_laplacian(&frame);
    cout << "Sharpness value: " << val << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.